# How to create a view with normalized properties in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have two tables in database, one is for individuals, and the other is their properties.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `person_ID` INT NULL ,
  `property` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

In the property table, I would have inserts like

(,1,'name','Mary')
(,1,'gender','Female')

(,2,'name','John')
(,2,'gender','Male')
(,2,'height','165cm')

How would I go about making a view statement that can generate these columns:
person_ID,name,gender,height,(and any other properties that might appear)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wouldn't simply merge the properties into the `person` table? This reminds me a bit too much of meta-databases. I, for one, would expect every person to have a name and a gender.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT
  p.ID, prop.name, prop.gender, prop.height
FROM
  person p
  JOIN
    (
    SELECT
      person_ID,
      MAX(IF(`property` = 'name', `value`, NULL)) AS name,
      MAX(IF(`property` = 'gender', `value`, NULL)) AS gender,
      MAX(IF(`property` = 'height', `value`, NULL)) AS height
    FROM
      property
    GROUP BY
      person_ID) prop
    ON p.ID = prop.person_ID;
```

Note, that in this solution all fields and values are hard-coded.

Comment: this normalization would require me making a custom query for each variable that needs to be normalized. I need something that can take any number of variables.

Comment: This tip may help you - http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html